# Right truncation in survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Im trying to censored in the right and it is not working. My code is the following:

```
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(mes, mes_2, estado, type = 'interval2') ~ 1,data = survival_clientes)
```

However, if I try with `type = 'interval'` it works.

I need interval2 because i have NAs for the right truncation, and this is really important to get the right interpretation.

Comment: 1. Please provide a reproducible example. 2. I assume you are using the `survival` package? 3. Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: There may be a difficulty with terminology. Truncation and censoring are different. Can you describe the processes that give rise to the data?